# Open file dialog on Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I use library jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js and jquery-1.9.1.js.
I have html code. I need one functionality, use JQuery, when user click on button, will show open file dialog. User will select button, and after that he open file, the path view on input "Path". How can I do this?

```
 <input type="text" id="Path">
 <button id="uploader" value="Upload">Browser</button>
```

Comment: Why not just use a normal file upload button? What is your end goal with this?

Comment: This is a security issue. Most browsers should not let you do what you want to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to use a separate text and button controls instead of `file` input?

```
Select a file to upload: <input type="file" name="file">
```

Don't forget that browsers will not display the full path of the file due to security issues.